# Print two arrays side by side in a multidimensional array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my code:

```
    function chunk(arr, size) {

        answer = [['']['']];

        firstHalf = arr.slice(0,size);
        secondHalf = arr.slice(size, arr.length);

        return firstHalf;
    }

    chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
```

My goal is to print the two cut up arrays side by side. I'm looking for a result like this:

```
    [[ 'a', 'b' ],[ 'c', 'd' ]]
```

I know I need to push the two seperate arrays somehow, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: By “print” you mean actually outputting the data somewhere, or are you trying to create a new _data structure_ of the format shown?

Comment: I'm just talking about returning it. (I'm really new to javascript and programming, so I'm not really sure what you're asking.)

Comment: note that most answers given so far including original question code are creating global variables and not using local `var` which can be very problematic

Comment: Alex, if any of us have solved your problem, please don't forget to mark one of the answers below as "accepted" by using the gray checkmark. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to create the data structure you're looking for. The modified function returns an array with your two split arrays in it.

```
function chunk(arr, size) {

  var firstHalf = arr.slice(0,size);
  var secondHalf = arr.slice(size, arr.length);

  return [firstHalf, secondHalf];
}

var out = chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function chunk(arr, size) {

    var answer = [];

    var firstHalf = arr.slice(0,size);
    answer.push(firstHalf);
    var secondHalf = arr.slice(size, arr.length);
    answer.push(secondHalf);

    return answer;
}


var myArray = chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2); // myArray === [['a','b'],['c','d']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can create and use a multi-dimensional array in JavaScript. There are better ways to do this. I have used the simplest method because you said you are new to programming.

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
   var answer = []
   firstHalf = arr.slice(0,size);
   secondHalf = arr.slice(size, arr.length);
   answer.push(firstHalf);    
   answer.push(secondHalf);
   console.log(answer);
}

chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
```